# .Net Core - Only one typescript file recognises the angular typing and the others don't

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I have added type definitions for angularJS and JQuery via node package manager in my .net core web project.

When I added an App folder to wwwroot, and a BookingApp.ts file within App, the angular namespace was recognised fine and I was able to add a module.

However when I add subsequent ts files the angular namespace is not recognised.. whether its in the same path as BookingApp.ts or not.

I understand the typescript definition manager has been deprecated so is it not enough to just leave the typings in node_modules? or are they supposed to be somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was adding a typescript file using the VS extension "Add New File" with shift + F2.

When I added it via "Add new item" or copied and pasted the previous one then it worked!

So be wary of using that extension to add typescript files.